# jQuery mouseout onto anything but <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I made my own right click context menu, and I have expandable options on the right click  menu when you hover over them. I want the expanded menu to close if the mouse leaves the right click menu so I used the following code:

```
    $('ul').live('mouseout', function(event) {
    // close code here
});
```

But the problem is the event gets called every time I move the mouse onto any of the `<li>` elements.

How do???

Comment: That behaviour may also be confusing; it's not the general way a context menu works. It will remain activated even when the user's cursor has left it.

Comment: Try changing `mouseout` to `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('ul')
```

That means all the `ul` elements. May be you can give it a class (or an id) and do

```
$('ul.theClass')
```

Or

```
$('#ulId')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change your the code to not bind 'ul' to mouseout because the 'ul' tag would wrap the 'li' tags else nothing you do would work.

A solution for this is that you change menu option title to a div or something else while retaining the menu options as 'ul' 'li' tags

Answer (score 0):

You should try in li try any one of this

```
 $('ul li.classnameforli').bind('mouseout','mouseleave' function(event) {
    // close code here
});
```

Or

```
 $('ul li.classnameforli').live('mouseout' function(event) {
    // close code here
});
```

Comment: Consider not to use live, and replace it by 'on', live will be removed in the future release.